# runConfigurations have wrong factoryName in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, run-configuration

I try to use the [Agera Android Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-agera/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2) with *Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5*. The problem is that the run-configurations do not show up - although I have checked them out from git again after opening the project first.

In other words: the project is already open in Android Studio and the run configuration files (e.g. `Step_1.xml`) exist in the expected directory `~/android-agera/.idea/runConfigurations` - but they don't show up in the run-configurations drop-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution/workaround that I found, is to manually change the `factoryName` in all run-configuration files from `Android Application` to `Android App`.

example for the fixed file `Step_1.xml`:

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="Step 1" type="AndroidRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android App">
```

Then the run-configurations show up immediately in the drop-down (i.e. you don't even need to close/reopen Android Studio).

Comment: this problem should be fixed now: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-agera/issues/6